# Play Youtube Videos just by Passing Video URL

Tags: php, jquery, html, youtube, html5-video

I have been searchin the net but nothing that works as i intend to. What i want is that i have a textfield where the user can pass the URL of a youtube video (in the back-end), then in the front end i want that video to be displayed to use that url. The point is that it wont show the video. When i use the iFrame it works but it needs the url with embaded like this

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vM89zeKimOY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It work fine but as you see the url is not the general url that u copy/paste from the url bar.

the URL of the video is this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vM89zeKimOY
```

so what i want is smth like this:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vM89zeKimOY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I dont know if there is a plug-in where you can just paste the url and it plays, or what im missing but a clue or any help would be much appruciated.

Comment: Look closelly and you will see that the embedded link can be concatenated pretty easy. Just take the code after v=? and place it in a embedded link template : `https://www.youtube.com/embed/` + THECODE

Comment: @kikyalex and how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using jquery you can simple achieve it.

Html

```
<input id="TextBoxURL" />
    <br />
    <div id="iframe">        
    </div>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#TextBoxURL').change(function () {
                var youTubeUri = $('#TextBoxURL').val();
                var youTubeVideoId = get_youtubeId(youTubeUri);
                loadYouTubeVideo(youTubeVideoId);
            }); 
        });

        function get_youtubeId(url) {
            var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
            var match = url.match(regExp);
            if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
                return match[2];
            } else {
                //error
            }
        }

        function loadYouTubeVideo(id){
            $('#iframe').append("<iframe width='560' height='315' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/"+id+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
        }
    </script>
```

I didn't include the validation part here with.

Cheers. Happy Coding..!!!

Comment: Thanx for your code Shana, i was wondering how can i write this code to be dynamic, like i read the variable from database and then display it, but only if the variable is set, if is not set then at the place of the video to display an image. ???

Answer (score 1):

```
var NormalLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vM89zeKimOY";
var theCode = NormalLink.substring(NormalLink.indexOf('?v=')+3);
var embedded = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+theCode;
```

FiddleLink:  http://jsfiddle.net/swm7v/2/

Comment: Thanx a  lot for your response. Can you write it in php?

Comment: just replace the javascript variables with the php ones. 
`<?php`
`$NormalLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vM89zeKimOY";`
`$theCode = $NormalLink.substr(strpos($NormalLink,('?v='))+3);`
`$embedded = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+$theCode; `
`?>`